# Baby cot furniture concern - toxins / volatile organic compounds

Tags: safety, crib

Our recent purchase of a baby cot and mattress seems to be giving off a strong smell of paint fumes. The manufacturer does not specify what chemicals were used, nor does it make any recommendations of "gassing out" (leaving it outside).

Further digging shows a whole bunch of concerns relating to [SIDS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudden_infant_death_syndrome), and a [recent study](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/24548111) apparently shows that 50% of a random sample contained known carcinogens.

I'm not looking to jump on the "organic-everything" train, but common sense tells me it's probably not healthy for our child to be breathing in paint/varnish fumes.

There are a couple of options;

- Purchase a solid wood (oak?) cot which has not been painted/varnished.
- Purchase a travel cot and replace with softer mattress
- Purchase mattress which has not been pre-treated
- Ignore the fumes and accept risk

The upsides of using a travel cost would be not needing a buffer pillow around the edges to prevent head injury or stuck arms/legs, but it is lighter and more likely to topple over as child gets older. Another upside is they cost 3 times less than wooden cots and good quality ones do not give off any volatile orgnic compunds.

However I'm not sure if there are other risks associated with long term usage of a travel cot (assuming the mattress has been switched out).

Any thoughts/advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: Our travel cot (port-a-crib) is currently occupied by a three-year-old on trips, and while he can easily climb out, he's never managed to tip it over -- nor have his older siblings managed to tip it over when THEY are climbing in and out with him. I think a more realistic disadvantage would be constantly bending all the way down (almost) to the floor to pick up and put down the infant!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't have the links at hand right now, but my wife looked into this extensively both for cribs for our first and for painting our then-newly purchased house.

Her decisions:

- Purchase a solid wood (not particle board or any other glued-type processed wood) crib.  Varnish/paint doesn't seem to be very flexible; any crib will be finished, and the natural wood cribs will have VOCs in the finish just as the white/etc. painted cribs will - often more.  (Wood finish/varnish is worse than paint in most cases.)
- Purchase one made in the USA (such as Land of Nod's Andersen cribs, which is what we went through).  USA (or Western European/EU) maker will likely use relatively less dangerous paints than in some other countries.
- Well ventilate the room so VOCs do not build up in large quantities.  Don't forget, your paint on the walls also contains VOCs likely, as will your floor if you have hardwood (and carpet has its own fun things!).
- Buy a mattress protector that fully encloses the mattress.

Most of the noticeable by smell VOCs leave fairly early on in the life (within a few weeks after painting/varnishing - and much of the noticeable by smell isn't actually VOC, so don't assume that is the case), if it's done properly; if you're still smelling them likely months+ after it was painted, it may be a sign of a bad painting job or some other problem.

You could consider buying a used crib; the VOC level drops over time, after around 5 years you won't have very many VOCs given off comparitively, and can easily re-paint with a safer paint.  I assume you're not in the US from your word choices, but if you are, don't buy a crib made before 2011 (which admittedly gives you a fairly narrow range of dates...) as they aren't legal to sell due to safety concerns (see [this link at the CPSC](http://www.cpsc.gov/en/Safety-Education/Neighborhood-Safety-Network/Posters/Crib-Rules/) for more details).

If you do the travel cot option, I don't necessarily think a softer mattress is a good idea.  Harder is better for SIDS purposes, and most kids that I've known are even very comfortable sleeping on hard wood floors.  I'd also not assume it gives off nothing dangerous; it's probably largely plastic wrapped around metal legs, and both the plastic and (less often) the metal can be significant sources of risk.  BPA wasn't thought to be dangerous for a while, nor were pthalates, so who knows what next be found dangerous in plastics.  Properly finished/treated wood should be okay.

You can also remove the finish from the crib and re-apply a low-VOC paint of your own; this isn't all that hard to do (something like a 6-8 hour job to remove, then a few hours of work plus waiting to dry for re-finishing/painting).  Paint is better than varnish if you have the choice.

Comment: Thanks for giving a quick and detailed reply, I really appreciate it. You've raised some interesting points and has certainly made me think twice. I think we'll either go with the sand/repaint, or purchase a replacement solid wood crib. Thanks again!